# How to find a class of text area under div using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, textarea

I am working with jQuery here. I have a div under I have one more div and I have a text area here I need to find a class of text area

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('function fired');
    $('.select').mouseleave( function () {
            alert('will hide');
            $('.select').hide();
        });
    });
  </script>
```

and here my html div tag:

```
<div id="btndiv" style="height:373px;width:800px; border:10px  solid orange ">
    <div id="btndiv1" style="height:360px;width:800px; border: 1px solid orange  ;">
        <textarea  rows="10"  class="select"  id="editor1"> </textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to call a class of textarea. How could I do this? I had tried but still not working any help will be appreciated - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
$(this).attr('class');
```

/

```
var outside = $('#btndiv1 .select').attr('class') ;

    $('.select').mouseleave( function () {
           alert('will hide');
           $('.select').hide();
           var inside = $(this).attr('class') ;
     });
```

Comment: it's working thank you verymuch and thanks for my reply mr. Sushanth

Answer (score 3):

```
    $("div textarea").attr("class")
```

or

```
    $("div div textarea").attr("class")
```

or

```
    $("#editor1").attr("class") //if u know id
```

or

```
     $("div#btndiv textarea").attr("class")  // if u know id of div
```

or

```
     $("div#btndiv").find("textarea").attr("class")
```

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific,

```
$('textarea','#btndiv1').attr('class');
```

Comment: jezen sory for asking how to integrate above function to my answer i did't get could you guide me plz